# Moving Perf Point 2010 content to 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, migration, performancepoint

I'm trying to migrate PerformancePoint content from a SharePoint 2010 instance to a 2013 instance.  I cannot do a database attach upgrade.  All Google has shown me is that I can move the content from 2010 to another 2010 server, but there's very little info about how to update it directly to 2013.

How can I migrate PerformancePoint content from 2010 to 2013?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**PerformancePoint services**

PerformancePoint Services use a database to store information. This database must be upgraded as part of a services database attach upgrade. So if you want to migrate from 2010 to 2013, i am sure that's the only option.

[http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj729802(v=office.15).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj729802%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

here is step by step guide to move the content with in 2010, try it may be worked for 2013.

[http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee661744(v=office.14).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee661744%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

http://denglishbi.wordpress.com/2010/11/20/migrating-performancepoint-2010-content-to-new-server/

Comment: I didn't believe it beforehand, but the method for 2010 did the trick, even to 2013.  Thanks!